# Why is my service not running?

Tags: android

I trying to create simple app that run a service when receiving sms. 
I write all the code and i still can't see any service that running on sms receiving.

The code

1. the service

   ```
   public class MainService extends Service {

   @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
       return null;
     }


     @Override
     public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        super.onCreate();

        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
      }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   return START_STICKY;
     }
   }
   ```
2. the BroadcastReceiver class

   ```
   public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            context.startService(new Intent(context, MainService.class));

             // TODO - complete the sms analyze
       }
   }
   ```
3. the AndroidManifest

   ```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



   <service android:name=".MainService"/>

   <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission> in your manifest ? or R u sure for onReceive() , it is running or not ?

Comment: yes, i add the RECEIVE_SMS , and the onReceive is no take action when sms is receive

Comment: Problem is in BroadcastReceiver. Everything in ur code seems fine. it should work now. if not then add permissions android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS and android.permission.READ_SMS in manifest. then try again. Plz let me know if working.

Comment: sorry .. not working also

Comment: ok, no worry, some one else will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
I also suffered this such issue earlier. I solved the same by using the flag android:enabled="true".

<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true"
      android:priority="2000000" >

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>

    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Actually by default it will be enabled .I don't how it will change later. Please see the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Else you can do one more thing that is the about the priority part. Could you please use a priority which is greater than 1000. 
Example: - android:priority="2000000".

In your android device you have sms applications which having the higher priority receivers. They may block the sms when they got.

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding the priority . please check. This time your problems will solves don't worry :)